# Is this explanation correct?

Tags: transmission-line

https://electricalbaba.com/travelling-wave-transmission-line/

In the middle of the script,

[ Since line is assumed to be lossless, whatever is the value of voltage wave and current wave at the beginning, the same will be at any time t. This means that, the magnitude of voltage and current wave at time t will be V and I respectively.

Hence the stored charge in shunt capacitance Q = VCx

and the flux in the series inductance Ø = ILx

But I = dQ/dt

```
     = CVdx/dt
```

But dx/dt = velocity of travelling wave = ν (say)

Therefore, I = CVν …….(1)

The voltage developed across the shunt capacitance,

V= dØ/dt

=ILdx/dt

= ILν

⇒V = ILν ……….(2) ]

Is this right?

Is possible that Voltage and Current is constant?

In the transmission line equation or the traveling wave theory, voltage and current is varying about position.

In lossless line, the magnitude of amplitude is constant, but the magnitude of voltage and current is fluctuating along traveling direction.

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-NKbD5BZG0

In the traveling direction, V is fluctuate.

In the traveling wave theory or telegraph equation,

dØ = I L dx   --->>>
v = dØ/dt = (I L dx)/dt = (dI/dt) L dx

But. In the above script,

dØ = I L dx   --->>>
v = dØ/dt = (I L dx)/dt = I L (dx/dt) = I L V(velocity)

Is this right?

Comment: Which part do you doubt?

Comment: @Andy aka
Is possible that Voltage and Current is constant?

In the transmission line equation or the traveling wave theory, voltage and current is varying about position.

In lossless line, the magnitude of amplitude is constant, but the magnitude of voltage and current is fluctuating along traveling direction.

Comment: The line is lossless hence the RMS values of voltage and current are not attenuated. In addition they travel together and this means the instantaneous ratio is also constant. Of course, if the line is not correctly terminated there will be reflections that cause standing waves and this can muddle things up.

Comment: @Andy aka
  https://ximera.osu.edu/electromagnetics/electromagnetics/waves/digInWaveEquation

Comment: Make your point not directly as a link but as a statement please.

Comment: @Andy aka    In telegraph equation, dv/dt and di/dt  term exists.  But  the script deal with V, I as constant.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what your trying to say or what point you are trying to convey.

Comment: @Andy aka     In telegraph equation, d(phi)=LdxI   -->   v=d(phi)/dt=Ldx(dI/dt). 
                                         But in the script, d(phi)=LdxI  --> v=d(phi)/dt=LI(dx/dt)=LIV

Comment: Your doubt was whether it is possible that V and I are constant and my reply is yes, they will be constant at all points along a lossless line. That is a fundamental thing about lossless t-lines.

Comment: The picture you have added is when the input of the t-line is driven by a sinewave and of course, the instantaneous value of a sinewave changes cyclically however, at any point on the lossless line and, at any time, the ratio of V to I remains constant. If you apply a step input (rather than a sinewave) V and I remain constant. In addition the video is inapplicable because it's considering a t-line with imperfect termination thus standing waves are generated. Take smaller steps and don't get confused by the more complicated scenarios until you are ready for them.

Comment: @Andy aka   Regardless of types of input,  the solution of general transmission line equation is voltage E(x)=(E_0+)(e^-rx)+(E_0-)(e^rx),  current I also same. In the lossless line, attenuation constant alpha is zero. So propogation constant is phase constant, j(beta). Then E(x)= (E_0+)(cosbx+jsinbx)+...   .   So E(x) is harmonic with position (not with time) or oscillating or fluctuating with position. Regardless of types of input.

Comment: @BriL your assertion is wrong. E(x) depends very much on the type of input. Consider a step input, the step propagtes down the line with zero before it's passed and V and I, constant, afterwards. However, if you input a sinewave, then the V and I will be sine in time at any given position. In a lossless line in the absence of a reflection, the magnitude of these will be constant at all positions, even if their instantaneous values are varying.

Comment: @Neil_UK    Thanks for you comment.   Then  where am I wrong in the   [[the solution of general transmission line equation is voltage E(x)=(E_0+)(e^-rx)+(E_0-)(e^rx), current I also same. In the lossless line, attenuation constant alpha is zero. So propogation constant is phase constant, j(beta). Then E(x)= (E_0+)(cosbx+jsinbx)+... . So E(x) is harmonic with position (not with time) or oscillating or fluctuating with position. Regardless of types of input.]] ?

Comment: @BriL It doesn't help to repeat the same misunderstanding buried in the same equations.  The equations cannot have a harmonic solution if the input is not harmonic! Start describing how some real signals propagate down the line, in English, or pictures, rather than maths. And that's an infinite length line, so you don't need to worry yet about reflections.

Comment: @Andy aka , Neil_UK   Thanks a lot for yours comments.    I will try to understand more.

Comment: Please change the title to deal with your question.  *Is this explanation correct?* has nothing to do with a specific topic.